# Why would XElement.Load accept a Stream?

Tags: c#, stream, xelement

Why does the method XElement.Load acccept a Stream?

I got stuck on this for a while because I was parsing it a Stream from an HTTP Web Response Stream and I thought it would convert the bytes into a string. However, that wasn't the case and I had to use StringReader to convert the stream into something the method would be able to read properly.

My original code that would compile but fail at runtime:

```
Stream datastream = response.GetResponseStream();
var xmlResult = XElement.Load(datastream);
```

The above would give an error that states "Root Element is missing". This can be resolved by using a StringReader and passing that instead.

Is there a case where a Stream will be used for this method?

Comment: Are you sure that `datastream` contains valid xml?

Comment: A stream would be used in any case where you are reading the XML from some kind of IO, including the example you have posted. If the specific example throws an exception then it suggests that the response is not valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an encoding issue. You can't parse XML off of bytes. You can only parse it from chars. The bytes of the stream must be converted to chars first.

It seems that after decoding to chars there is no root element or there is garbage before the root element.

I don't now what `XElement.Load` does by default. It seems to guess the encoding (`XmlTextReaderImpl.DetectEncoding`). Find out what encoding your data has and layer a `StreamReader` between the `Stream` and the XML framework. Set the correct encoding.